# Nginx -- Error 400: Origin is not allowed to make this request

Tags: nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm setting up a reverse proxy for MeiliSearch with Nginx. When sending a POST request from an origin, I get a `400: Origin is not allowed to make this request` error. However, if the request does not have an origin, everything works correctly.

Interestingly, the response also includes different headers whether or not the origin is present.

### Requests/responses

#### Working request

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Type | application/json |
| X-Meili-API-Key | asfasdfasdfasdfsafsdfasdfadsfsadff |

#### Working response

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server | nginx/1.18.0 |
| Date | Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:49:02 GMT |
| Content-Type | application/json |
| Content-Length | 252 |
| Connection | keep-alive |
| Access-Control-Allow-Origin | * |

As you can see, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a wildcard as it should be.

#### Failing request

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Type | application/json |
| X-Meili-API-Key | asfasdfasdfasdfsafsdfasdfadsfsadff |
| Origin | https://example.com |

#### Failing response

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server | nginx/1.18.0 |
| Date | Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:49:02 GMT |
| Content-Length | 252 |
| Connection | keep-alive |

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is now missing.

### Configuration

This is the full configuration file.

```
server {
server_name example.com;
location / {
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    }

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Meili-API-Key";
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:7700;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name example.com;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was reported for the v0.18.0, there was an problem with actix-cors

https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/pull/1185

A new version was released with the fix: v0.18.1

https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/releases/tag/v0.18.1

Download the new MeiliSearch version and the problem will go away :)

Comment: Thanks! Thought for sure this was an Nginx error, otherwise, I would have asked over on the repo.